# I keep getting Server error try again 30 seconds on Google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I created a simple springboot app and tried deploying I keep getting this error

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

I tried accessing my url

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Comment: Go to Cloud Logging and look at your logs. You should have more insight

Comment: Your app is crashing or failing to start correctly. Review the logs.

Comment: I saw this error.      java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/example/demo/DemoApp/DemoApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 64.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0

Comment: did you export JAVA_HOME? :  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/